# Clutch pedal was down during driving but is up again?

Tags: clutch

During driving clutch pedal suddenly stuck to the floor however it has since recovered.

Clutch fluid is present.  Since this is intermittent or only happened once, what may be the likely cause?  Is it a sign of a clutch on its way out?

Comment: How is your clutch fluid level? That may indicate a leak on the system or a failing clutch master cylinder. Are you sure there wasn't anything that made it stuck on the floor? Like a floor mat or something... Also, I'm curious to see under what conditions you can reproduce the issue...